# NoClassDefFoundError even though jar is in the module path Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, module-path

I am working on a vanilla Eclipse project and trying to avoid using Maven.

I have added Jackson modules to the module path as an external jar. When I do so, the import statement no longer shows an error but when I run my program I get the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper   at
> bitcoin.PriceConverter.getJsonFromUrl(PriceConverter.java:48)     at
> bitcoin.PriceConverter.main(PriceConverter.java:26) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ... 2 more

Line 48 in PriceConverter is ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();

[image: modulepath]

I have googled extensively and found that my classpath is potentially broken however, all of the answers are from outdated versions of Eclipse and I cannot work out how to fix this problem.

I tried the same thing with Gson and had the same problem however, yesterday I added the json-20210307.jar and it worked fine.

Can anyone explain what is happening here and guide me on how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you are not using a modular project (no module-info.java) so the jars should in the Classpath section, not the Modulepath.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your reply! it has solved my problem and allowed me to research further into project types.